# Complex OrderBy: Statement body cannot be converted to expression tree

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, sql-order-by

Basically I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects from my database (using Entity Framework 6), however I want the items to be ordered in a certain way.

I have tried the following:

```
context.Coordinates.OrderBy(x =>
    {
        double latDif = Math.Abs(centerLat - x.Longtitude);
        double lngDif = Math.Abs(centerLng - x.Latitude);

        double dif = latDif + lngDif;
        return dif;
    });
```

However, the compiler shows the following error:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an
>   expression tree

I have looked this up and understand that I can't use a statement body (the curly brackets) when calling orderby in linq-to-sql.

**However how can I then do a complex orderby like the one above, without loading all the entries?**

By the way, in case you are wondering I'm trying to order the items by those which are closest to the center coords (centerLat and centerLng).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
context.Coordinates.OrderBy(x=> Math.Abs(centerLat - x.Longtitude) + Math.Abs(centerLng - x.Latitude));
```

if you are looking to order based on multiple columns then use

```
.OrderBy(x=> new {

    // fields or props or columns
 })
```

Comment: Ahh, why didn't I think of that!
Thanks a lot that works great!